# Put a multidimensional array into a one-dimensional array

Tags: c++, arrays, multidimensional-array

I've got a question. I'm writing a simple application in C++ and I have the following problem:
I want to use a two-dimensional array to specify the position of an object (x and y coordinates). But when I created such an array, I got many access violation problems, when I accessed it. I'm not pretty sure, where that violations came from, but I think, my stack is not big enough and I shuld use pointers. But when I searched for a solution to use a multidimensional array in heap and point on it, the solutions where too complicated for me.

So I remembered there's a way to use a "normal" one-dimensional array as an multidimensional array. But I do not remember exactly, how I can access it the right way. I declared it this way:

```
char array [SCREEN_HEIGHT * SCREEN_WIDTH];
```

Then I tried to fill it this way:

```
for(int y = 0; y < SCREEN_HEIGHT; y++) {
    for(int x = 0; x < SCREEN_WIDTH; x++) {
        array [y + x * y] = ' ';
    }
}
```

But this is not right, because the char that is at position y + x * y is not exactly specified (because y + y * x points to the same position)
But I am pretty sure, there was a way to do this. Maybe I am wrong, so tell it to me :D
In this case, a solution to use multidimensional array would be great!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You don't want `y + x*y`, you want `y * SCREEN_WIDTH + x`.  That said, a 2D array declared as:

```
char array[SCREEN_HEIGHT][SCREEN_WIDTH];
```

Has exactly the same memory layout, and you could just access it directly the way you want:

```
array[y][x] = ' ';
```

Comment: Yes, I tried the multidimensional array, but it did not worked, because everytime, when I reached array[0][57] (57 of 80), the application crashed, because of an access violation (I don't know, why it does). But thanks for your quick answer :)

Comment: You'll have the same access problem with a 1D array indexed the way I describe or with a 2D array. They have literally the same memory layout.  If you have a bug with one, you'll still have the same bug with the other.  Is the array very large? Are you putting it on the stack?

Comment: I thought that, too. When I learned to use multi-dimensional array, it said, that C++ is not able to build them and uses instead a big 1D-array. But for some reason, your solution works, and the 2D does not. The array has following size: 9 * 80. I do not know exactly, wether it is on the stack or not. I did not use pointers, because I do not really understand how to use them, yet (I am a really beginner, I started to learn c++ few days ago :D)
But I did not give the array as an argument, so I do not know, wether it is on the stack anyway or not...

Answer (score 3):

```
char array2D[ROW_COUNT][COL_COUNT] = { {...} };
char array1D[ROW_COUNT * COL_COUNT];

for (int row = 0; row < ROW_COUNT; row++)
{
    for (int col = 0; col < COL_COUNT; col++)
    {
        array1D[row * COL_COUNT + col] = array2D[row][col];
    }
}
```

You access the correct element for your 1D array by taking "current row * total columns + current column," or vice-versa if you're looping through columns first.